# Find css destination in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, centos

I'm using Rails 4, CentOs and this gem https://github.com/acrogenesis/owlcarousel-rails . And this gem includes 2 css files. Where i can find css files of this gem? I already requered it in my appliation.css

```
 *= require owl.carousel
 *= require owl.theme
```

and it's working great. i just can't find this style file

Comment: awesome you are using the plugin! :) feel free to open an issue at the repo if you ever have a problem.

Comment: @acrogenesis great plugin. Thanks a lot! But I already solved it with standart css :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here: https://github.com/acrogenesis/owlcarousel-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets

Or from your project directory on console:

```
$ ls "$(bundle show owlcarousel-rails)/vendor/assets/stylesheets"
```

Comment: yup. ls telling me, but it's empty. or these files invisible?)

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` after editing the gemfile?

Comment: of course. css working great. maybe i should restart the server? or i'll just edit css in my css file.